# undefined reference to `printf'

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, makefile, nasm

***test.c*** and ***kernel.asm*** are in the folder ***src***, ***Makefile*** is in the folder ***Debug***, just like that:

```
src
    test.c
    kernel.asm
Debug
    Makefile
```

All these files are very simple codes. But if I run `make` in the folder `Debug`,I will get the following error:

```
ld -Ttext 0x30400 -o test ../Debug/kernel.o ../Debug/test.o
../Debug/test.o: In function `Print_String':
test.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `printf'
```

Can someone tell me why? Contents are as follows:

***test.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>

int m = 1;
void Print_String()
{
    printf("TEST");
}
```

***kernel.asm***

```
extern m
extern Print_String

[section .text]
global _start
_start:
    mov eax, m
    call Print_String
```

***Makefile***

```
# This Program
TARGET  = test

# All Phony Targets
.PHONY : everything clean all

DIR     = ..

OBJ     = $(DIR)/Debug/kernel.o $(DIR)/Debug/test.o
C_FILE  = $(DIR)/src/test.c
K_ASM   = $(DIR)/src/kernel.asm

ASM     = nasm
LD      = ld
CC      = gcc

CC_FLAG  = -c -g
ASM_FLAG = -f elf
LD_FLAG  = -Ttext 0x30400

# Default starting position
everything : $(TARGET)

clean :
    rm -f $(TARGET)

all : clean everything

kernel.o : $(K_ASM)
    $(ASM) $(ASM_FLAG) -o $@ $<

test     : $(OBJ)
    $(LD) $(LD_FLAG) -o $@ $(OBJ)

test.o   : $(C_FILE)
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAG) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: adding `-lc` to ld command line may help.

Comment: Unless you have your own version of printf somewhere, you'll have to link with the C runtime library (`-lc`).

Comment: You may need another ld flag besides "-lc", "-I/lib/ld-linux.so.2". ld, by default, looks for "...so.1" which give a confusing "file not found" error!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have your own version of `printf` somewhere, you'll have to link with the C runtime library.

Pass the option  `-lc` to the `ld` command.

Comment: for those trying to find how to use -Lc argument to specify the folders, here is a sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361841/manually-link-standard-library-in-mingw