# manually link standard library in MinGW

Tags: c, mingw, ld

I had some trouble getting MinGW to recognise libraries for CSFML. I've had to manually link each library using the linker. Now I dont have the standard library that gets linked automatically from a simple gcc call.

```
bbroo@DESKTOP-1F1J3SM ~/Shaders
$ ld shaders.o libcsfml-system.a libcsfml-window.a libcsfml-graphics.a csfml-system-2.dll csfml-window-2.dll csfml-graphics-2.dll
shaders.o:shaders.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `__main'
shaders.o:shaders.c:(.text+0x4bc): undefined reference to `sleep'
```

What is the name of the standard library in MinGW and how do I link to it in LD?

I know this doesnt answer the question, but compiling with this works:

```
gcc shaders.c libcsfml-system.a libcsfml-window.a libcsfml-graphics.a csfml-system-2.dll csfml-window-2.dll csfml-graphics-2.dll
```

Comment: Why not set the library search path when compiling it? I believe the option is `-L`

Comment: I've tried many options and none of the others got this far.

Comment: Use `gcc` as the linker for C programs

Comment: hey buddy, long time no see

Answer (score 3):

Using 'ld' in not obvious. Since gcc successfully compiles your project, you can reproduce linking stage directly with 'ld' with the following steps.

1. Compile with 'gcc' with -v option added. This will produce a lot of text, you may want to redirect it to file with '2>out'
2. Find the last line that begins with 'COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='
3. After this line there will be a list of gcc option which regulate behavior of 'ld'. From this line extract the following: two -L options which point to main library folder and gcc-specific library folder; after that a sequence of used object modules and libraries. Copy these to your 'ld' command line. The list is rather large. **The order of objects and libraries is important!**

Here is the sample command line which successfully links simple test program:

```
ld -Lc:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0 -Lc:\MinGW\lib -o test.exe crt2.o crtbegin.o test.o -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt crtend.o
```

You may need to check paths, copy *.o files to your folder or add path to them and add your libraries.